# Como configurar Flutter corretamente para o cloud_firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter

Olá, alguém pode me ajudar!
Estou configurando projeto flutter com acesso firebase.
Estou usando o package firebase_core: ^1.3.0 e cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2
Funciona para emulador android ok.

A conexão com o firebase funciona normalmente, mas quando adiciono o package cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2 ou a anterior o xcode fica executando o pod install e nao mostra mensagem alguma e para ai.

Já tentei com as versores 12.0, 13.0 e 14.0 do iOS no podfile.

obrigado

Answer (score 0):

No app em produção da empresa, estamos com o pacote `cloud_firestore` na versão `^2.1.0` e nosso `target 'Runner'` utiliza a versão 7.11.0 do SDK IOS do Firestore.

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  
  # Flutter Pod
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '7.11.0'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

Você pode ter uma visão melhor do que está acontecendo dentro do `pod install` rodando ele manualmente. É só abrir o terminal na pasta IOS do projeto Flutter e rodar `pod install`.

Comment: Boa tarde! fiz o que vc sugeriu, mas não resolveu o problema..

Comment: @MarcosAurelioBinoti Poderia compartilhar o seu Podfile? Esse arquivo fica dentro da pasta ios/.